# How to open folders in VSCode via Terminal in a fresh state?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It appears that VSCode always opens a folder in with the last UI state it had.

I'm looking for something like Sublime's `remember_open_files: false`, or in other words, I would like VSCode to open up with a clean UI state regardless of what state the UI was in the last time the folder was open.

What's happening now:

```
cd my-project-folder/
code .
# VSCode opens folder with saved UI state
```

What I want:

```
cd my-project-folder/
code .
# VSCode opens folder with fresh UI state
```

Comment: Tried doing it with commandline options but it doesnt seem possible. Maybe they don't support this particular option. `code -n .` somehow restores the last session for that particular folder.

Comment: @Kronos Thanks for the help! Sucks that it can't be done right now but I appreciate you helping me. If you take your comment and make it an answer I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I tried to do it through command line using the command

```
code -n .
```

which should have opened VS code in current folder with a new session but it does not seem to work at all. I believe that `code .` seems to ignore the `-n` new session option and restores the previous session for the folder. **So this feature is probably not implemented in VS code.**

(Refer [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) for the commandline options for VS code.)

Comment: The `-n` flag is for new window and DOES work (ie, try `code -n` and it'll open a new instance). However, it is not considered when opening a folder. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/051ba11238f0a58ff2773b30d7968a49af2c45de/src/vs/platform/environment/common/environment.ts#L16

Comment: From `Version: 1.35.1` it support `code .` to open a new instance of VSCode in current terminal's directory

Comment: If the command don't work for you, check @Bjorn.B answer. Basically you need to open Visual Code, then the Command Palette and select the option to install code command in PATH command.

Comment: The link referenced in the answer for the CLI option for VS Code is good; but, also noteworthy is making the most out of the integrated terminal [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).  Especially if you're like me and prefer to stay far away from the Windows CLI and Powershell and make use of BASH and/or ZSH, which VS Code does a great job with.

Answer (score 58):

this is the command that works for me on windows

```
code -r .
```

Comment: @JerodG  `-r` is for "reuse-window". See here: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options

Comment: might not be the direct answer to the original question, but was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Pay attention the period "." at the end. `code -r .`

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: works on ubuntu as well

Comment: This wants to close existing open windows for this folder.

Answer (score 49):

From inside VS Code built-in terminal, cd into your project folder/directory and enter command:

```
code -a .
```

Note period at end.

This will open your current directory/project folder without opening a new window.

Comment: It does probably not work for files. So the a flag opens a new instance, dot is for "reusing the current window"

Comment: `-a --add <folder>                 Add folder(s) to the last active window.`

Answer (score 32):

If you are using a Mac, you need to first install the VSCode command amongst the shell command list.

Do this:

1. Open VSCode
2. press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
3. type `shell command`
4. select **Install code command in path**
5. navigate to any project from the terminal and type `code .`

Comment: After step 4 I get an EACCESS error

Comment: Getting "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/code'"

Answer (score 26):

Part of the answer on [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294176/how-to-install-visual-studio-codes-code-command-permanently) worked for me. Basically, make sure VSC is in the Applications folder. Then open the Command Palette (F1 or ⇧⌘P on Mac) and type `shell command` to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.`

Restart Visual Studio Code if it's open. In terminal, navigate to the folder you want to open in VSC, and type `code .`. Hopefully it should work for you.

Comment: All other suggestion did not work except this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

`code .` opens VS Code at the current terminal folder

Comment: you can also use this command with the git bash terminal

Comment: this actually helped me

Comment: btw before using that you have to register it, to do that, open VSCode and pres cmd+shift+p, type shell and press enter, this will do the registration for you

Answer (score 8):

If you are using VS Code [Version: 1.50.0] then open your command prompt and go to your project's directory and just run the command:

```
code -a .
```

i.e. [Also can see the photo]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMmkH.png

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem on Mac.

I solved it in the following steps:

1. I opened the "Command Pallete" on the VSCode. This can be done by CMD + SHIFT + P
2. Type "shell"
3. Click on 'Install code command in path'
4. Give an administrator password
5. You will get a message that it has been installed
6. Now run "code ."
   NB: Make sure you already cd into the folder you want to open before you run code .

Answer (score 5):

```
$ code . --user-data-dir=.
```

This will open Visual Studio Code in current working directory. I use Bash with Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Comment: `--user-data-dir=.` won't help much , since it will add sub user folder to each project folder you open .

Answer (score 5):

I am using VS Code Version 1.24.1 (As of the time of original posting).

If you want to open a folder through the terminal, you can execute the command:

```
code -n name_of_your_folder/
```

or

```
code -n path_to your_folder/
```

Same thing goes for a file, and these open VS Code in a new window.

Also, note that you should have VS Code installed.

You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I checked through all of the settings available in the VSCode preferences for me, and I don't think there is a way to do this.

There are some settings related to what VSCode window instance that folders will open into, but nothing that seems similar to Sublime Text's `remember_open_files` setting.

The closest thing I found was running `code --user-data-dir .` (feel free to replace `.` with some other directory so you don't pollute your current working directory) from the terminal to specify that VSCode shouldn't remember ANY previous settings, but this seems like overkill for what you're trying to accomplish (as VSCode will literally run as if it's the first time it's being run after a fresh install).

**EDIT**: I just discovered a `View: Close All Editors` command in the command palette (CMD + SHIFT + P). The keyboard shortcut for OSX is `CMD + K, CMD + W`, and this will close all the files you have opened!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! Like you mentioned, it doesn't appear that there is anything like `remember_open_files` in vscode but The `View: Close All Editors` is a handy tip. Regardless, vscode will still remember state in other folders but running `View" Close All Editors` at the end of every session might be one way to mimic the behavior I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open folder with vscode, you just go to folder ( you can user terminal or file explorer) with terminal, and do "code ."

Answer (score 0):

To get the right folder in VS Code v 1.50.1 Terminal I tried a lot of options which didn't work for me. At the end I found very easy solution. I went to File->Open Workspace and found that my Workspace had the wrong folders inside it, which I simply deleted (from Workspace only!). Then I opened the folder I needed in my Workspace, opened Terminal->New Terminal, and everything worked perfectly well. Please let me know if this will work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This command works to open a specific folder in VS code using terminal

```
code -r Documents/VS/C++/
```

here -r switch is used to open a file or a folder in an already opened VS code window
and then you specify the path of the file or folder you want to open
if you want to open it in a new window use -n switch instead of -r

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with VSCode on Linux:

```sh
cd path/to/project
codium .
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every mentioned answers, what's work from me is this:-

I created a shell script to open  folders.

```
$ sudo nano  /usr/local/sbin/code2

/usr/bin/code-oss -n --user-data-dir '/home/myusername/.config/Code - OSS2/'  -a $@

$ sudo chmod +x  /usr/local/sbin/code2
```

You can remove `--user-data-dir '/home/myusername/.config/Code - OSS2/'` from the script if you want to use default code-oss config folder.

When I want to open a folder, I use the command like this :-

```
$ code2 .
```

I add this command `code2` to open with option `thunar` to open folders directly from files manger.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory in the command pallet on your computer the navigate to the the specific folder using `cd`
the type `code .` and that will open the folder and the files in it inside vs code. works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio Code is installed using flatpak then a bash alias can help launch the application from the terminal.

alias code="flatpak run com.visualstudio.code"

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can make keyboard shortcut in VScode from

`file ->preferences -> keyboard shortcuts` and click on keyboard shortcuts JSON file
[image]

And add this code for it

```json
 {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithCwd",
        "args": {
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
 }
```

After add this code you can open terminal in any directory by open any file in this directory and press `ctrl+shift+h` or any shortcut that you want to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

`$code folder "folder name"`

Example:

`$code folder variables/`

*Folder "variables" opened in VSCode*

ps. It opens a new VSCode page with the main folder and all content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your project folder & simply write this:

```
code .
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it a simpler way just by three steps. I am currently in a project folder and want to open another folder in vs code using the cli or terminal. What I first did is navigated in the folder which I wanna open in vs code inside the terminal. Once I m inside that particular directory or folder I simply typed the command :

```
start code .
```

**This will open that directory or folder in a new vs code window.**

The complete process is :

1. open the terminal is vs code
2. navigate to the folder u want to open
3. once u r inside that particular folder type the command :

   start code .