# Can I use VSCode's command palette explorer to open folders on Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to set the file explorer for the **File: Open Folder...** shortcut to use the same one **File: Open Recent...** uses on Mac?

Right now it opens Finder and I don't really like how I have to start using my mouse/trackpad to navigate I'm quite enjoying just using my keyboard when in VSCode

I've been using VSCode with WSL until this point

Comment: Command+Space opens spotlight. You can easily open recent files from there without ever touching the mouse. Or for more power you can get something like Alfred

Comment: Thanks @AdamHarte, but what I'm looking to do is open a folder I've never opened before, in my VSCode, replacing the current workspace. Spotlight allows me to find the folder I've just created, but it doesn't allow me to open it in the current VSCode window.

Comment: This is literally how it works when connected over ssh, it's great. Odd that it's not even available normally, Finder is easily 10x slower.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closes solution to your problem is discussed [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941146/10985412) and particularly the answers for Mac.

You can open the folder with the following command `code . --user-data-dir=.`, and the linked answer is how to add `code` if its not accessible on Mac.

Provided command you would use from the terminal to open a new instance, after navigating to the folder.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Running `code . -a` has similar results and it's what I've been using to solve my issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight > Terminal > goto Folder > run `$ code .`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer, however opening a new instance of vscode is not my intention, `code . -a` has been working for me.